# Tweepy: lookup_users() cannot perform write actions, error 261

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Hello I am using the Twitter API via Tweepy on Python, since it is a read function, I don't understand why I get the following message:

```
[{'message': 'Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://help.twitter.com/forms/platform.', 'code': 261}]
```

When I checked my developer portal I found the following message:

```
This App has violated Twitter Rules and policies. As a result, certain functions will be limited. An email has been sent to ******@gmail.com with details. For assistance, submit a support ticket.
```

Which is funny since I have only used the API with my own credentials/user for:

```
public_tweets = api.user_timeline()
lookup_users = api.lookup_users(user_ids=[user_id])
```

**Additional info:**
I gave read, write, post permissions to my app

1. Why cannot I perform writing actions if this is a read function?
2. Is there any way I can manage this issue with my app? Twitter is not responding to my appeal

Answer (score 0):

This error code seems to indicate an issue with the app permissions, unspecific to the endpoint:

> Code 261 - App cannot perform write actions.
>
> The App that you are using with the API does not have the proper [permission level](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions) set for its access token and access token secret. Please navigate to the 'Keys and tokens' tab on the [Twitter Apps](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps) dashboard and check the permission levels assigned to your access token and access token secret. If it is set to anything other than 'Read, write and Direct Messages,' then you are going to have to adjust the settings under the 'Permission' tab and regenerate your access token and access token secret to apply the new settings.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

Beyond submitting a support ticket and waiting for a response, I don't think there's much else you can do in terms of the restriction itself.